# Heroku worker not logging or printing

Tags: python, heroku, celery, worker

I have a Heroku worker dyno that is not printing or logging anything to the Heroku logs.

I set up the worker in my procfile so that all logging.info() commands should work:

```
worker: celery -A tasks worker -B --loglevel=info
```

Here is the tasks.py file:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
import json
import settings, logging
import datetime
from mongoengine import DoesNotExist

app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker=settings.get('rabbitmq_bigwig_url'),
    backend='amqp')

@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
def test():
    print 'Not printing!'
    logging.info('Also not printing!')
```

How do I get print/logging messages to write to Heroku's logs? I've tried all the Heroku log commands (heroku logs, heroku logs --ps worker, etc.)

Comment: Heroku is outputting logs such as app[worker.1]: [2015-04-18 19:22:45,581: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task tasks.awake (tasks.test) but is not logging 'Not printing!' or 'Also not printing!'

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, you initialize `logger = get_task_logger(__name__)`, but then when you mean to log something, you're using `logging.info(..)`.
In your final line, replace `logging.` with `logger.`.